# SQLite3 How to combine the IN operator with the LIKE operator to get partial text matching to a subquery?

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to do detect duplicates in a database. I have came up with a MWE of what I am trying to do. Not every id column has a value but the id nevertheless may be in the filename. I am trying to find all rows which have an id which appears in a filename which is in a different row.

[image]

This query is kind of what I am looking for, but the problem is that doing exact matches

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE id IN (
    SELECT filename FROM items
);
```

The IN operator is shorthand for:

`name IN ("Bob Walters", "Alice Reed")` ==> `name == "Bob Walters" OR name = "Alice Reed"`

However I want an operator that does this:

`_________` ==> `"%" || name || "%" LIKE "Bob Walters" OR "%" || name || "%" LIKE "Alice Reed"`

I am looking for what I can put in the blank space to achieve this operation. My table has just over 10,000 rows (so the solution doesn't necessarily have to be optimized for millions of rows).

Comment: Is that data your example table, or an example of what you want the query to produce, btw? I assumed that you want only the row with the null id to be returned, as the filename has an id that's in a different row, but if it's something else I'll go back and revise my answer. Plus everything after that table doesn't match up with it or the first paragraph... so on second thought I don't know *what* you want...

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. I want all the rows which have an id that appears in the title field in a different row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Things I've tried

1. Using the `WHERE EXISTS` operator in conjunction with the `LIKE` operator (~50secs on a 10,000 item database)

   ```
   SELECT * FROM items AS i1 WHERE EXISTS (
       SELECT * FROM items AS i2 WHERE i1.id != i2.id AND i2.filename LIKE '%' || i1.id || '%'
   );
   ```
2. Using the `WHERE EXISTS` operator in conjunction with the [`instr`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#instr) function (~50secs on a 10,000 item database)

   ```
   SELECT * FROM items AS i1 WHERE EXISTS (
       SELECT * FROM items AS i2 WHERE i1.id != i2.id AND instr(i2.filename, i1.id) != 0
   );
   ```
3. Using the `WHERE EXISTS` operator in conjunction with the `LIKE` operator along with looking only at rows with a null id (~30secs on a 10,000 item database)
4. Using the `WHERE EXISTS` operator in conjunction with the [`instr`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#instr) function along with looking only at rows with a null id (~30secs on a 10,000 item database)
5. In Python, get a list of ids, then for each ID call the database looking for matches (~17secs on a 10,000 item database)
6. In Python, get a list of ids and filenames from the database, then do the search in Python (~10secs on a 10,000 item database) `<--` solution I used

#### Other Possible solutions

1. Using the `WHERE EXISTS` operator in conjunction with the `REGEXP` operator
2. Enabling the FTS4 full text search extension and creating a virtual table, so using the `WHERE EXISTS` operator in conjunction with the `MATCH` operator (or another FTS4 operator)
3. Using SQLAlchemy in Python
4. Restructuring the database (for example pulling out ID look alikes from filenames into a separate id column, so we can do exact column matches instead of wildcard searches)

#### Code for my Solution

```
statement_id = 'SELECT * FROM items WHERE id IS NOT NULL and id != ""'
cursor.execute(statement_id)
ids = cursor.fetchall()

statement_title = 'SELECT * FROM items WHERE title IS NOT NULL AND title != ""'
cursor.execute(statement_title)
titles = cursor.fetchall()

matches = []
for id in ids:
    for title in titles:
        if id['id'] in title['title']:
            matches.append([id, title])
```

#### Conclusion

In conclusion, the solution is ugly but I think given the circumstances (it's a personal project, I won't be doing this data deduplication operation all that often, etc). I think the full text extensions or restructuring the database might be nicer solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You want EXISTS, not IN. Try:

```
SELECT *
FROM items AS i
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM items AS i2
              WHERE i.filename LIKE '%' || i2.id || '%' AND i.filename <> i2.filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQLite 3+, you may try using the `REGEXP` operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM items i1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM items i2
              WHERE i2.filename REGEXP '\b' || i1.id || '\b' AND
              i1.id <> i2.id);
```

If your version of SQLite does not support `REGEXP`, then you *can* use `LIKE` in its place:

```
SELECT *
FROM items i1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM items i2
              WHERE i2.filename LIKE '%' || i1.id || '%' AND
              i1.id <> i2.id);
```

I highlighted *can* above, because the problem with `LIKE` and wildcards is that it would not only match exact matches, but also substrings, e.g. if `id=34983` appeared as a *substring* of another id in a filename in a different record, there would be a false positive.

Comment: Sqlite doesn't support REGEXP unless using the ICU extension (Which isn't compiled into most OS-provided versions) or another third-party extension that provides it.

Comment: @Shawn The thing is, using `LIKE` is flawed, because the most it can assert is that an `id` appeared as a _substring_ inside another filename.  So, this would match all positive matches, but runs the risk of including false positives too.  My suggestion to use `REGEXP` is a good one, I think, and any reader who has it available should definitely use it over `LIKE`.

Comment: I do not have `REGEXP` available on my system but the behavior with `LIKE` would be preferred as I wouldn't want to be miss any duplicates. That being said the second option worked but it is slow. It took me 51060ms to get back 376 rows. I am ok with 1000ms but 50,000ms is too much. When I was looking up the `EXISTS` statement I found this: "SQL statements that use the EXISTS Condition in SQLite are very inefficient since the sub-query is RE-RUN for EVERY row in the outer query's table. There are more efficient ways to write most queries, that do not use the EXISTS Condition."

Comment: Unfortunately, there is not much which can be done to speed this up.  Indexing won't help, because of the `% ... %` wildcard.  `EXISTS` or similar logic is necessary here, because for each record's `id` we have to scan the entire table's `filename` to see if there might be a match.